# MLRunNotFoundError: there are no offline targets for this feature set

Tags: python, feature-store, mlrun

I got this error during FeatureVector call:

```
  ...
  File "C:\Python\emptyVectore\venv\lib\site-packages\mlrun\feature_store\retrieval\base.py", line 105, in start
    return self._generate_vector(
  File "C:\Python\emptyVectore\venv\lib\site-packages\mlrun\feature_store\retrieval\local_merger.py", line 71, in _generate_vector
    df = feature_set.to_dataframe(
  File "C:\Python\emptyVectore\venv\lib\site-packages\mlrun\feature_store\feature_set.py", line 930, in to_dataframe
    raise mlrun.errors.MLRunNotFoundError(
mlrun.errors.MLRunNotFoundError: there are no offline targets for this feature set
```

Part of source code (which generated the issue):

```
import mlrun
import mlrun.feature_store as fstore
...
features = ["fs-01.fn2", "fs-02.fn3"]
vector = fstore.FeatureVector("my-vec", features)
vector.save()

df = fstore.get_offline_features(vector).to_dataframe()
print(df)
```

Did you solve the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the same issue in case that featuresets were empty. I see these solutions:

**1. Initial ingest**

If you add to the featuresets initial ingest value than FeatureVector will return relevant values (without exception).

**2. Use wrapper**

You can also create wrapper for read FeatureVector and in case of this specific exception MLRunNotFoundError, return None value. See example:

```
def get_vector(vector) -> pd.DataFrame:
    try:
        df = fstore.get_offline_features(vector).to_dataframe()
    except mlrun.errors.MLRunNotFoundError:
        df=None
    return df
```